# Loading pre-trained resnet model to cleverhans model format

Tags: python, tensorflow, resnet, cleverhans

I am trying to load a pre-trained ResNet model from the `MadryLab CIFAR-10` challenge into `CleverHans` to compute transfer attacks.

However restoring the saved models into the `model_zoo.madry_lab_challenges.cifar10_model.ResNet` object does not work. It appears to restore fine initially, but when I try to actually use the model, I get an error such as:

> Attempting to use uninitialized value
>   ResNet/unit_3_1/residual_only_activation/BatchNorm/moving_mean

The easiest way to reproduce this error is to actually just run the provided `attack_model.py` example included in `CleverHans` here:

https://github.com/tensorflow/cleverhans/blob/master/examples/madry_lab_challenges/cifar10/attack_model.py

It encounters the same error after loading the model when it tries to use it, on both `adv_trained` and `naturally_trained` models.

Is there a workaround to this problem?

It seems the other option is to use the `cleverhans.model.CallableModelWrapper` instead, but I haven't been able to find an example of how to use that.

Comment: Which version of python, tensorflow, cleverhans are you using?

Comment: @NicolasPapernot python 3.6.8, tensorflow 1.13.1, cleverhans 3.0.1

Comment: Would you mind trying with python 2 and an older version of tensorflow? I think the specific example you are pointing to hasn't been updated in a while. My guess would be tensorflow v.1.7 or 1.8 had a different API